# Media name as link to file

Tags: 8, files, media

I have a "Document" media bundle, and I have a custom view mode called "Embed".

In that view mode, I have removed everything except the `media name` property and my `document` file field.

For `media name` the only format available is `plain text`, with an option to "Link to Media". This provides a link like `media/2`, where you can click on a link to download the file.

For my `document` field, I get `Generic file` (the file name with a link to it), `RSS enclosure`, `Table of files`, and `URL to file`.

Does anyone have a simple way to generate a link like `Generic file` but show the `media name` instead of the file name? e.g. `Handbook` vs `handbook__2017_fin_updated_some_other_rubish_26.pdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How I did this**

As per @Berdir's suggestion, I have done this in the theme. However, instead of hijacking the output in the media (which is perfect for control based on the media display mode), I have chosen to set the filename.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to get the media entity from the file, so I use `template_preprocess_media` which has both the media entity and the file entity, and then the `setFilename()` method.

Loosely:

```
file = $variables['elements']['#media']->field_file->entity;
$file->setFilename($variables['name']);
```

For improved accessibility, you should "show" the file size and type, and while this available here, it felt cleaner to do this in `file-link.html.twig` where a bunch of other nice things are added to the attributes for you.

Comment: Coming in a bit late, but here's an example of a custom file display formatter which uses the media entity "name" field as the link text:  https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/imclean/3051849

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible with just the formatter configuration, someone would need to create a "Link to file with entity label" formatter, which would also not be that complicated.

But you can do it quite easily directly in a media template, the name would be something like `media--document--embed.html.twig` and the content then looks like this:

```
<div{{ attributes }}>
  <a class="document-link" title="{{ name }}" href="{{ file_url(elements['#media'].field_document.entity.uri.value) }}" target="_blank" rel="noopener">{{ name }}</a>
</div>
```

I also included a target and noopener rel here, but that's of course up to you.

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm finding. But this doesn't feel like something that should be done in the theme. Seems like pretty standard need, unless I'm missing something… You can achieve this with the `field_group_link`, but that feels like overkill.

Comment: Patches are always welcome to add new features to contrib/core modules (media is now in core, so new features won't be added to media_entity). But it's not as straight-forward as you might think, someone else might want to use a separate field for the displayed name, or the description of the file field, or use an icon (in my example I actually removed a fontawesome icon within the link) and so on, so I see nothing wrong with doing this in the theme

Answer (score 2):

```
function template_preprocess_media(array &$variables) {
  $media = $variables['media'];
  $name = $media->getName();
  if (!empty($name)) {
    $mediaArray = $media->toArray();
    if (!empty($mediaArray['field_media_file'][0]['target_id'])) {
      $fileId = $mediaArray['field_media_file'][0]['target_id'];
      $file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fileId);
      $file->setFilename($name);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Still working for Drupal 9, just had to replace 'field_media_file' with 'field_media_document'

Answer (score 1):

The best way to implement this is not to set filename. Instead, you should set the #description of the file. In the following example, I have a media of a bundle called "file" and in it, I have a file field called "field_media_file". Then I set the description of each file to be the media name.

```
if ($variables['media']->bundle() == 'file' && !empty($variables['content']['field_media_file'])) {
    foreach (Element::children($variables['content']['field_media_file']) as $delta) {
      $variables['content']['field_media_file'][$delta]['#description'] = $variables['name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting! I'm not working on anything that would use this now, but I'll give this a go next time!

Comment: The problem with this approach is that file description is not mandatory and leaves open the likelihood that editors will not supply it. There is an old issue about this which is not getting anywhere fast. See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2320877

Answer (score 0):

This module seems like it does what you are asking (BTW had the same question which led me here): https://www.drupal.org/project/link_plain_text_formatter

Comment: Thanks, I had seen Drupal 7 at the top of the description and dismissed this :/ However, it doesn't appear to help here.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a file link preprocess function that can look up the media entity for the file and and then set the link text accordingly. Replace "field_media_file" with your media entity's field name. If you want to do this for more than one media type, you'll have to expand it accordingly as well.

```
function template_preprocess_file_link(array &$variables) {
  $file = $variables['file'];
  $result = \Drupal::entityQuery('media')
    ->condition('bundle', 'document')
    ->condition('field_media_file.target_id', $file->id())
    ->execute();
  if (!empty($result)) {
    $media = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('media')->load(reset($result));
    $variables['link']->setText($media->label());
  }
}
```