# Load a media entity/object from a fid?

Tags: entities, files

I have the file ID (fid), and the rest of the file object.

I need to get fields from the parent media entity, but I can't find anything about loading a media entity from a file object.

Drupal 8.4.0

**Update**

I asked this question in relation to another: [Media name as link to file](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246195/media-name-as-link-to-file/250304#250304)

As far as I could find Kevin's comment is correct.

Comment: The File object won't have a reference to a Media entity using it. You need to load the Media entity and access the file that way.

Comment: Just realised I didn't say what version of Drupal I'm on. @Kevin, it that for D8?

Comment: Wouldn't a file entity be related to a media entity via an entity reference field? And doesn't core have reverse entity reference field logic built-in? Feels like you should be able to get that pretty easily

Comment: @Clive, exactly my thoughts, I guess it's that logic I'm asking about.

Answer (score 6):

Using the service `file.uses` you get the file media object:

Example:

```
$file is a loaded file object.
$file = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('file')->load($fid)
$result = \Drupal::service('file.usage')->listUsage($file);
```

`$result` should now contain an array like so:

```
$result['file']['media']['4372'] = 2;
```

Where `4372` is the media id. and `2` the times the file is used.

From the docs of `listUsage`:

```
@return array
   *   A nested array with usage data. The first level is keyed by module name,
   *   the second by object type and the third by the object id. The value of
   *   the third level contains the usage count.
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently needed to do the same, and came up with the following.  First, load the file entity from the fid:

```
$fid = 1000;
$file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fid);
```

Then, call [file_get_file_references](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!file!file.module/function/file_get_file_references) on the file entity:

```
$references = file_get_file_references($file);
```

Per the docs, you will get back a nested array of the referencing field names, entity types, entity ids, and finally the referencing entity itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
use Drupal\media\Entity\Media;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

function myFunction() {
  $node_load = Node::load($nids);
  $media_field = $node_load->get('media_field_machine_name')->getString();
  $media_entity_load = Media::load($media_field); 
  $uri = $media_entity_load->field_media_video_file->entity->getFileUri(); 
  $banner_media_url = file_create_url($uri);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$file` is a the loaded file object.

```
$file = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('file')->load($fid)
$result = \Drupal::service('file.usage')->listUsage($file);
```

Is very relevant answer and more optimized result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; maybe you could indicate the difference with the one answered by FLY?